# What URL's are allowed as domains for your app?

Tags: facebook, url, dns

I am trying to set up my Facebook app, but I keep getting error messages when I try to input my app domain.

This is the first error message that I receive.
"This must be derived from Canvas URL, Secure Canvas URL, Unity Binary URL, Site URL, Mobile Site URL, Page Tab URL or Secure Page Tab URL. Check and correct the following domains: www.livelocalandprosper.com"

So I tried adding an "s" after the http and got an error message that said that "top level domains are not allowed".

I also tried using the web app host site's URL, but it wouldn't accept that either.  I got the same error message about top level domains.

I have asked the web app host and my website provider, but didn't get any helpful answers there.

Could someone please enlighten me on what I need to do?

Answer (score 5):

Before you can fill in a domain in the app settings, you need to add a Platform, such as a Canvas app, and add the appropriate URL.

i.e. I have a test app, and after adding the Canvas app URL `http://bithoop.la/canvas.php?ref=facebook` and saving it, I can add `bithoop.la` to the domain box.

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s53/sh/66259600-af67-46de-b34c-a9cb0f0cf319/db0384a2fdbe7c7a9cea57bdaafad84b